# prove $Θ(t)=⁡\lim_{ϵ\to0+}\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{-∞}^{+∞}dβ\frac{e^{iβt}}{β-iϵ}$ for $Θ(t) =1 \text{ if t>0, and 0 else t<0} $

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

How to prove the following:
$$Θ(t)=⁡\lim_{ϵ\to0+}\frac{1}{2πi} \int_{-∞}^{+∞}dβ\frac{e^{iβt}}{β-iϵ}$$
for
$$Θ(t) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if } t>0 \\
0 & \text{else } t<0
\end{cases}$$

I tried to solve the integral using exponential integral function using a substitution $u=iβt+ϵt$ which gave me;
$$Θ(t)=⁡\lim_{ϵ\to0+}\frac{e^{-ϵt}}{2πi}\left.Ei(iβt+ϵt)\right\rvert_{-∞}^{+∞} =⁡\lim_{ϵ\to0+}⁡e^{-ϵt}$$

But it gives $1$ at both cases. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You can also use the complex integration to find the answer. For $t>0$ you close the contour in the upper-half of the complex plane. Due to Jordan' lemma the integral along the arch $\to 0$ at $R\to\infty$. As $\epsilon>0$, you have one pole in the upper half-plane, and the residue is not zero for $t>0$. You get $\Theta(t)=\oint =Res =1$ at $\epsilon\to 0^+$. For $t<0$ you have to close the contour in the lower half-plane (to get the integral along the arch $\to 0$). But in the lower half-plane you do not have poles, and the integral along the contour ($=\Theta(t)$) is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral can be rewritten as:

\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\beta}{\beta^2+\varepsilon^2}e^{\beta i t}\,d\beta +\frac{\varepsilon}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{\beta i t}}{\beta^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\beta\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}

The second term in \eqref{zero} can be estimated as follows:
$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{\beta i t}}{\beta^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\beta=\frac{1}{2\pi \varepsilon}\int\frac{e^{\beta i t}}{(\beta/\varepsilon)^2+1}\,d\beta=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int \frac{e^{\beta\varepsilon i t}}{\beta^2+1}\,d\beta=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|t\varepsilon|}
$$
The last identity follows from the relationship between the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and the doubly [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

Similarly, the first term in \eqref{zero}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\beta}{\beta^2+\varepsilon^2}e^{\beta i t}\,d\beta&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \frac{\beta}{\beta^2+1}e^{\beta\varepsilon i t}=\frac{1}{i\varepsilon}\partial_t\Big(\frac{1}{2i}e^{-|t\varepsilon|}\Big)\\
&=\operatorname{sign}(t)\frac{1}{2}e^{-|t\varepsilon|}
\end{align}

The conclusion follows immediately.

Comment: It cannot be solved without using the cauchy and exponential distributions?

Comment: I just mentioned the Cauchy/double-exponential relation in case you were not aware of the Fourier transform of $1/(x^2+1)$. Of Course, the Fourier transform of $t\mapsto e^{-|t|}$ is easy to obtain (without knowledge of probability distributions) and then the Fourier inverse will give you what you need. The kernels involved also are related to the Poisson PDE if analysis is your inclination.

Comment: How is it will be with the fourier transformation? I think its much better and it's what I need, can you please explain more detaily in an answer to this question? I really appreciate the solution using the probability distributions.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $e^{-|t|}$  is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\pi it s} e^{-|t|}\,dt$. Split the integral two pieces: one over $(-\infty,0]$; the other over $(0,\infty)$. Those are simple integrals. You will get something that has a term go the form $constant\times (1+|2\pi s|^2)$; that give you the relation between $1/(1+s^2)$ and $e^{-|t|}$ via the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: (+1) ... similar indeed to the other referenced question