# Derivation of Heaviside step function in its integral form

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, distribution-theory

I'm studying the Heaviside step function: $$ \theta(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if}& x>0\\
0,&\text{if} &x<0
 \end{cases} $$
I have problem to prove that this function can be represented as:
$$ \theta(\tau) =  \frac{-1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\omega}{\omega + i\varepsilon}e^{-i\omega\tau} $$
I was thinking about integrating this expression using residue theorem, but I haven't done it for a long time, and it didn't work out and now I don't think it is the right way. So my question is how you derive such representation?

Comment: Make the substitution $\omega\rightarrow -\omega$, then average the two integrals.

Comment: @eyeballfrog What do you mean?

Comment: To compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\omega}{\omega + i\varepsilon}e^{-i\omega\tau}$ you need to close the contour, adding a semicircle, either in the upper or lower half-plane depending on $sign(\tau)$. The integral on the semicircle is zero due to the exponential decay. In one case there will be a pole inside the contour, in the other case there won't.

Comment: It should be $\varepsilon \to 0^+,$ shouldn't it? For $\varepsilon \to 0^-$ you instead get $-\theta(-\tau)$ (or equivalently, $\theta(\tau)-1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approch that circumvents contour integration.  Proceeding, we note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\omega+i\varepsilon}e^{-i\omega \tau}\,d\omega&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\omega -i\varepsilon}{\omega^2+\varepsilon^2}e^{-i\omega \tau}\,d\omega\\\\
&=-i\varepsilon \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega \tau)}{\omega^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\omega -i \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\omega \sin(\omega\tau)}{\omega^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\omega\\\\
&=i\left( \frac{d}{d\tau}-\varepsilon \right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega \tau)}{\omega^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\omega
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we need only evaluate the integral, for $\varepsilon>0$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega \tau)}{\omega^2+\varepsilon^2}\,d\omega=\frac1\varepsilon \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega \epsilon \tau)}{\omega^2+1}\,d\omega=\frac\pi{\varepsilon} e^{-|\varepsilon \tau|}$, which can be accomplished by a number of real analytical methodologies.

Thus, for $\tau\ne 0$, we find that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\omega+i\varepsilon}e^{-i\omega \tau}\,d\omega=-2\pi i \theta(\tau)$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: I find it interesting that the value of the first integral, $$-i\pi (\operatorname{sign}(\tau)+\operatorname{sign}(\epsilon)) e^{-|\epsilon\tau|},$$ has a symmetry between $\tau$ and $\epsilon$ despite them having different roles.

Comment: (+1) Hi @MarkViola, hope everything is well. A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4561518/121671)

Comment: @OliverDíaz Hi my friend.  I hope you're doing well.  Thank you for the (+1).  Much appreciated.